# Default route not capturing query string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an Asp.Net MVC application where I want the `Home\Index` controller action to take an optional parameter which will be used by the server to decide which view to return.

So I defined the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "LogOn",
  url: "logon/{id}",
  defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
  );
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "register",
  url: "register/{id}",
  defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Register", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
  );      
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
   );
```

These routes allow me to simplify my url's by not having to specify the `Home` controller so url's like `mysite/Home/logon` are simplified to `mysite/logon`.The Home/Index action where all non resolved urls go looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id="")
{
    if (id.Contains("App"))
      return View("AppView")
    return View();
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I send `localhost/#app/41` to my server, I expect the `id` to be `#app/41` but it isn't. The `id` is always set to null.

Is there something wrong/missing with my route definition?

Comment: You mean `#` or `?`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a [Fragement identifier](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html) as some query-string value because the Fragment Identifier is not being sent to the server at all, it is only used by the Browser (mainly for [Anchor links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)).

If you insist on using `#`, you'll have to encode it first, but that won't look as pretty as you expect.

Comment: Oh that explains it! thank you. I will do some more tweaking and see if I can figure a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is not an accepted query string character. If you want to pass `#` as query string parameter, you should encode it to `%23`. Your correct URL should look something like

```
localhost/?id=%23app/41
```

Comment: Oh that explains it! thank you. Let me do some tweaking and see if I can get around this.